# Display A Woocommerce Welcome message on 'my account' page immediately after user registers?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a function which displays a woocommerce info message immediately after the user has registered along the lines of:

```
Thank you for registering - Click here to start shopping
```

Would anyone be able to help me?

Comment: is user logged in { } essentially

Comment: http://spyrestudios.com/wordpress-tutorial-display-a-user-welcome-message/

Answer (score 1):

Go to class-wev-email-verification.php and find the function create_temp_user($user_id)

Find this if statement:

```
if ( ! is_object( $woocommerce ) || version_compare( $woocommerce->version, '2.1', '<' ) ) {
```

and change the contents of it to look as follows:

```
if ( ! is_object( $woocommerce ) || version_compare( $woocommerce->version, '2.1', '<' ) ) 
{
    $woocommerce->add_message( 'message' );
}
else{
    wc_add_notice('message', $notice_type = 'success');
}
```

If that alone doesn't work you can try adding this in above it:

```
 if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) == 0 ) {
     $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( 2445 );
     $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
 }
```

That worked for me!

I used this help forum to find the answer:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/great-plugin-messages-not-working

Hope that helps!

Comment: wc_add_notice() -- that's what I was after! Thanks